# Laravel 5.3 Search function in API

Tags: php, laravel, api, search, laravel-5.3

I'm implementing an API for `front end and mobile apps` now i'm working on `search function` where a user may type `column name` or any `data` i should be able to provide the data they request in a JSON format

i really don't know how to query based on the data they input, so for i did this

in my controller

```
public function getSearchResults(Request $request) {
    $search_drivers = Driver::all();

    return Response::json([
        'data' => $search_drivers->all()  // i know this is not cool, i need to query based on the input data
    ]);
}
```

my model is

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Driver extends Model
{
   use SoftDeletes;

   protected $fillable = [
                           'agent_id',
                           'registration_center',
                           'registration_date',
                           'sponsor_name',
                           'event_name',
                           'registration_id',
                           'profile_photo',
                           'first_name',
                           'last_name',
                           'role',
                           'date_of_birth',
                           'marital_status',
                           'phone_number',
                           'alternate_phone_number',
                          ];

   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

and in my routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    }); 
    Route::resource('drivers', 'DriversController');
    Route::resource('search', 'DriversController@getSearchResults'); //search route
});
```

and the parameters meight be

```
   http://localhost:8000/api/v1/search?data=name(maybe any column data from above model)
```

could you please tell me or give me some example how to `query and return as json`

Thank You

Comment: Provide some more info like table name,  model code, query params, etc...then only SO can help you.

Comment: @Amit Gupta thank you for your response, i have update my post with my model

Comment: You have not provided the query params. Give some example of that.

Comment: something like this `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/search?data=name(maybe any column data from above model)`  thank you

Comment: Just as a heads up, in looking at your url, you should consider using json web tokens instead of sending the data through the url. Just a security precaution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can chain `where` for each field you need to search as:

```
$data = $request->get('data');

$drivers = Driver::where('first_name', 'like', "%{$data}%"))
                 ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', "%{$data}%"))
                 ->get();

return Response::json([
    'data' => $drivers
]);
```

You can add more `where` clauses if you want.